# Spark bulk insert to MS-SQL

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, bulkinsert

I have a table on Hive which contains 920 649 653 records.
I would like to insert that table in MS-SQL.

I use [azure-sqldb-spark](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sqldb-spark) lib.

> spark2-shell --master=yarn --jars azure-sqldb-spark-1.0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar

```scala
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.bulkcopy.BulkCopyMetadata
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._

var bulkCopyMetadata = new BulkCopyMetadata
bulkCopyMetadata.addColumnMetadata(1, "Id_Util_Donnees_Texte", java.sql.Types.INTEGER, 0, 0)
bulkCopyMetadata.addColumnMetadata(2, "Id_Util", java.sql.Types.INTEGER, 0, 0)
bulkCopyMetadata.addColumnMetadata(3, "Id_From", java.sql.Types.INTEGER, 0, 0)
bulkCopyMetadata.addColumnMetadata(4, "IdD", java.sql.Types.INTEGER, 0, 0)
bulkCopyMetadata.addColumnMetadata(5, "Valeur", java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR, 8000, 0)
bulkCopyMetadata.addColumnMetadata(6, "dCollecte", java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP, 0, 0)
bulkCopyMetadata.addColumnMetadata(7, "dInsertion", java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP, 0, 0)
bulkCopyMetadata.addColumnMetadata(8, "dMAJ", java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP, 0, 0)
bulkCopyMetadata.addColumnMetadata(9, "id_marque", java.sql.Types.INTEGER, 0, 0)


val df = spark.table("analyses_tmp.import_sofinco_Util_last_Donnees_Texte").coalesce(10)


val bulkCopyConfig = Config(Map(
  "url"               -> "db_url",
  "user"              -> "user",
  "password"          -> "*******",
  "databaseName"      -> "Hadoop",
  "dbTable"           -> "dbo.Util_Last_Donnees_Texte",
  "bulkCopyBatchSize" -> "4000",
  "bulkCopyTableLock" -> "false",
  "bulkCopyTimeout"   -> "6000"
))

df.bulkCopyToSqlDB(bulkCopyConfig, bulkCopyMetadata)
```

After 2h, I received this error and the whole insert **rolled back** :

```
9/04/11 20:17:22 ERROR cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Yarn application has already exited with state FINISHED!
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 1 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:837)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:835)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop(DAGScheduler.scala:835)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onStop(DAGScheduler.scala:1848)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop.stop(EventLoop.scala:83)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:1761)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$8.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1931)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1361)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1930)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend$MonitorThread.run(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:106)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2074)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:929)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:927)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply$mcV$sp(Dataset.scala:2675)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2675)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2675)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$withNewRDDExecutionId$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3239)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewRDDExecutionId(Dataset.scala:3235)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.foreachPartition(Dataset.scala:2674)
  at com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect.DataFrameFunctions.bulkCopyToSqlDB(DataFrameFunctions.scala:72)
  ... 51 elided
```

Do you see any reason why this error happened ? 
Do you have any recommendation on my settings, should I change anything to make the process faster ?

Comment: If YARN shut down your job with ID `application_xxxxxxx_xxxx` before it was complete, then it had a reason. Check the job status in ResourceManager, browse the logs for AM and Executor containers.

Answer (score 2):

You can force YARN to ignore this by setting up the following properties in yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: So, you assume that the job failed because the Spark executor consumed more RAM than was granted by YARN. Without seeing the actual error message in the YARN logs. Is it just a random guess?